# GeoJSON support in ArcObjects 10 .NET

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, geojson, openlayers-2, .net

i am currently trying to build a geoprocessing application using OpenLayers and ArcObjects,
I have some features that user draws on openlayers and i need to send these features to arcobjects for further processing.so i need a common feature format between these two systems.

### solution 1

first i have tried getting esri-json support on openlayers with agsjsadapter but i got some unhandled exceptions - still trying to succeed.

### solution 2

currently i am trying to convert a geojson format feature to Igeometry or Ipolygon on arcobjects, but i couldn't find any support for this in arcobjects.

i guess i need to solve this issue with one of the solutions above.